# PL SQL Function is not raising User defined exception

Tags: exception, plsql

I have defined a user-defined exception but my function is not raising the exception .

****Spec*****

```
FUNCTION get_property_id (
    p_owner IN app.bc_entities.entity_id%TYPE,
    p_object_type_id IN app.bc_custom_attribute_masters.object_type_id%TYPE,
    p_custom_attribute_master_id IN 
    app.bc_custom_attribute_masters.custom_attribute_master_id%TYPE,
    p_non_rev_controlled_p IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0

)
RETURN  NUMBER;
```

****BODY*****

```
FUNCTION get_custom_attribute_master_id (
    p_owner IN app.bc_entities.entity_id%TYPE,
    p_object_type_id IN app.bc_custom_attribute_masters.object_type_id%TYPE,
    p_property_id IN NUMBER,
    p_non_rev_controlled_p IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0

)
   RETURN  app.bc_custom_attribute_masters.custom_attribute_master_id%TYPE


    IS

     l_custom_attribute_master_id 
     APP.BC_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_MASTERS.CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_MASTER_ID%TYPE;
     l_object_property_id NUMBER := 0;
     v_sql varchar2(32767);
     r_error bc_errors%rowtype;
     TYPE templatecurtype        IS REF CURSOR;
     c_result                    templatecurtype;
     l_column_name VARCHAR2(50);
     invalid_property_id EXCEPTION ;

BEGIN

     r_error.code_unit := 'Get_Custom_Attribute_Master_Id';
     r_error.error_context := 'Calling Get_Custom_Attribute_Master_Id ';
     r_error.error_data := ' Get_Custom_Attribute_Master_Id :Property Id :'||to_char(p_property_id)||', OBJECT_ID:'||to_char(p_object_type_id);

     FOR V_ROW IN 
     (SELECT * FROM app.CUSTOM_PROPERTY_TABLES_DEFS WHERE object_type_id = 
     p_object_type_id AND
(
(p_object_type_id = 20 AND REV_CONTROLLED_P = p_non_rev_controlled_p) OR (p_object_type_id <> 20 AND NVL(REV_CONTROLLED_P,0) = NVL(p_non_rev_controlled_p,0) ) )
     )
  LOOP

        IF v_row.FIRST_PROPERTY_COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN
           l_column_name := v_row.FIRST_PROPERTY_COLUMN_NAME;
        ELSE
           l_column_name := v_row.PROPERTY_COLUMN_NAME;
        END IF;

        v_sql := ' SELECT civ.'||l_column_name || ' FROM '||v_row.table_name ||' civ WHERE '||
                   v_row.property_column_name ||' = :property_id ';

        dbms_output.put_line ( '1-v_sql '||v_sql);


        r_error.error_data := v_sql;

        OPEN c_result FOR v_sql
        USING p_property_id ;

        FETCH c_result INTO l_object_property_id ;
        CLOSE c_result ;
        IF l_object_property_id IS NULL THEN
           RAISE invalid_property_id;
        END IF;

        v_sql :='Select civ.custom_attribute_master_id FROM ' || v_row.table_name||' civ WHERE civ.' || l_column_name || '= :property_id and civ.custom_attribute_master_id is not null 
                 and rownum = 1';

        dbms_output.put_line ( '2-v_sql '||v_sql);

        OPEN c_result FOR v_sql USING l_object_property_id ;
        FETCH c_result INTO l_custom_attribute_master_id;

        CLOSE c_result ;
        RETURN l_custom_attribute_master_id   ;

  END LOOP;

EXCEPTION

    WHEN invalid_property_id THEN
    r_error.error_stack := dbms_utility.format_call_stack()||chr(10)||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace();
    r_error.message :=  ' p_property_id ( '||p_property_id||' ) is invalid  ';
    r_error.error_code := SQLCODE;
    r_error.notified_p := null;
    PKG_ERROR.LOG(p_code_unit=>r_error.code_unit
                 ,p_message=>r_error.message
                 ,p_application=>V_APPLICATION
                 ,p_database_name=>V_DB_NAME
                ,p_error_owner=>p_owner
                ,p_error_user=>p_owner
                 ,p_error_module=>V_MODULE
                 ,p_error_object=>V_APP_OBJECT
                 ,p_error_type=>app.pkg_error.error
                 ,p_error_code=>r_error.error_code
                 ,p_error_stack=>r_error.error_stack
                 ,p_error_context=>r_error.error_context
                 ,p_error_data=>r_error.error_data
                 ,p_notified_p=>r_error.notified_p);
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20098, r_error.message ) ;


     WHEN OTHERS THEN
    r_error.error_stack := dbms_utility.format_call_stack()||chr(10)||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace();
    r_error.message := SQLERRM;
    r_error.error_code := SQLCODE;
    r_error.notified_p := null;
    PKG_ERROR.LOG(p_code_unit=>r_error.code_unit
                 ,p_message=>r_error.message
                 ,p_application=>V_APPLICATION
                 ,p_database_name=>V_DB_NAME
                 ,p_error_owner=>p_owner
                 ,p_error_user=>p_owner
                 ,p_error_module=>V_MODULE
                 ,p_error_object=>V_APP_OBJECT
                 ,p_error_type=>app.pkg_error.error
                 ,p_error_code=>r_error.error_code
                 ,p_error_stack=>r_error.error_stack
                 ,p_error_context=>r_error.error_context
                 ,p_error_data=>r_error.error_data
                 ,p_notified_p=>r_error.notified_p);
    RAISE;

END get_custom_attribute_master_id;
```

Comment: Are you sure that "IF l_object_property_id IS NULL" condition is achieved?

Comment: Thanks . Got the problem. I have mistakenly assigned 0 in the declaration and this condition was not getting achieved